# Joint Random Variables- example using pair of dice

Tags: probability

Say I roll a pair of fair dice, let $X=$ the number of even numbers that show up on the roll (for example you roll a $2$ and a $3$, then $X=1$ for the $2$ that was rolled). I'm using Joint Random variables, and we are trying to find $F_x(2)$ or in other words the actual value of $P(X\le 2)$.

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this problem, in the past we have use combinations to compute the probability, however I don't know how to do that in the context of this problem. What I did was write out all $36$ possible outcomes for rolling a pair of die and found the $P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)=1$. I have a feeling that this is incorrect but any guidance that anyone could give would be very helpful, thank you

Comment: You can't have more the two dice come up even, so I don't see how the probability of getting at most two even dice could be anything other than 1.

Comment: Indeed,  When you throw two die, the amount of die that show even results is exhaustively $0, 1,$ or $2$ .  So $F_X(2)=1$ .

Comment: Please: Don't write $F_x(2)$ when you mean $F_X(2).$ If one does not distinguish between $X$ and $x$ then one cannot even understand something like $P(X\le x). \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} F_X(2) &=\mathsf P(X{\leq}2)\\ &=\mathsf P(X{=}0)+\mathsf P(X{=}1)+\mathsf P(X{=}2)\\&=(\tfrac 36)^2+2(\tfrac 36)^2+(\tfrac 36)^2\\&=1\end{align}$$

This is not surprising, because the only supported values for $X$ are $\{0,1,2\}$, so the event of $X\leq 2$ is a certainty.

Comment: Why do you write `X{\leq}2` rather than `X\leq1` in MathJax code. Can't you see the result? You get $X{\leq}2,$ without proper spacing, instead of $X\leq2. \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

When two six-sided dice are rolled there 36 possible outcomes:

```
(1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4) (1, 5) (1, 6)
(2, 1) (2, 2) (2, 3) (2, 4) (2, 5) (2, 6)
(3, 1) (3, 2) (3, 3) (3, 4) (3, 5) (3, 6)
(4, 1) (4, 2) (4, 3) (4, 4) (4, 5) (4, 6)
(5, 1) (5, 2) (5, 3) (5, 4) (5, 5) (5, 6)
(6, 1) (6, 2) (6, 3) (6, 4) (6, 5) (6, 6)
```

Of those, 9 pairs have no even numbers:

`(1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 5), (3, 1), (3, 3), (3, 5), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 5)`

Hence, the probability that there are no even numbers is $\frac{9}{36} = \frac{1}{4}$.

Similarly, there are 8 pairs that have no odd numbers:

`(2, 2), (2, 4), (2, 6), (4, 2), (4, 4), (4, 6), (6, 2), (6, 4) and (6, 6)`

So, the probability of 2 even numbers is $\frac{8}{36}= \frac{2}{9}$.

Rather than count all pairs that have one even number, just calculate:
$$ 36- 9- 8= 36- 17= 19$$

The probabiity of 1 even number is therefore 19/36.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't think the probability they seek is for a single even number.